# Can one expand $(a + b)^{{i}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm solving a transcendental equation and I currently have:
$$-i\ln(ix + \sqrt{1 - x^2}) = \frac{1}{(i\ln(x) + \sqrt{1 - \ln(x)^2})^i}$$
I don't know how to binomially expand the bottom denominator expression with $i$, you cannot expand it with the same rules applied to binomials with positive integer powers, because when you organize nCR rows for each term, R cannot increase to $i$ because it isn't a real number - is the following binomial expression possible to expand?
$$(a + b)^i$$

Comment: The binomial coefficients are defined for any complex $z$ (and a non-negative integer $r$) as $zCr = z(z-1)(z-2)\cdots (z-r+1)$ and you can apply the binomial theorem, but the result is a series, not a finite sum. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: @jjagmath Does it *have* to be a series though? The binomial expansion with a negative integer eg. $(a + b)^{-2}$ produces a "series" because the conventional form of a binomial expansion is not a fraction, but the conventional form is useless in the context of solving an equation, as something like this could easily be expressed as $\frac{1}{a^2 + 2ab + b^2}$ instead of an infinite series.

Comment: You could always use Euler's formula, which gives you exact coefficients - $(a + b)^i = e^{i\ln(a + b)} = \cos(\ln(a + b)) + i\sin(\ln(a + b)).$

Comment: To handle the complex number within the natural log, you can use the fact that $\ln(a + bi) = \ln(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}) + i\arctan(\frac{b}{a}).$ The complex definitions of sin and cos should also help.

Comment: Please avoid subject lines that consist only of Mathjax. It messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a^2+2ab+b^2}$ is not considered the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^{-2}$.

Answer (score 3):

#### Expand $\left( a + b \right)^{i}$

##### Expansions

There are several ways to expand $\left( a + b \right)^{i}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( -i,\, y;\, y; 1 - a - b \right),\, \quad \left( \forall y \right) \tag{1.}\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= -i \cdot \left( 1 - a - b \right)^{i} \cdot \operatorname{B}\left( 1 - a - b;\, -i,\, i \right) \tag{2.}\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \exp\left( \ln\left( a + b \right) \cdot i \right) \tag{3.}\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \cos(\ln\left( a + b \right)) + \sin(\ln\left( a + b \right)) \cdot i \tag{4.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Where [$\operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( a,\, b;\, c; z \right)$ is the Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) and [$\operatorname{B}\left( x;\, p,\, q \right)$ or $\operatorname{B}_{x}\left( p,\, q \right)$ is the Euler's incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

##### Derivations

**$\left( 1. \right)$:**
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( 1 - z \right)^{-x} &= \operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( x,\, y;\, y; z \right),\, \quad \left( \forall y \right)\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \left( 1 - z \right)^{-x}\\
i = -x &\wedge a + b = 1 - z\\
-i = x &\wedge 1 - a - b = z\\
\end{align*}
$$

**$\left( 2. \right)$:**
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{B}\left( x;\, p,\, q \right) &= \frac{x^{p}}{p} \cdot \operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( p,\, 1 - q;\, 1 + p; x \right)\\
\operatorname{B}\left( x;\, -i,\, i \right) &= \frac{x^{-i}}{-i} \cdot \operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( -i,\, 1 - i;\, 1 - i; x \right)\\
-i \cdot x^{i} \cdot \operatorname{B}\left( x;\, q,\, p \right) &= \operatorname{_{2}F_{1}}\left( p,\, 1 - p;\, 1 + q; x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

**$\left( 3. \right)$:**
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \exp\left( \ln\left( \left( a + b \right)^{i} \right) \right)\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \exp\left( \ln\left( a + b \right) \cdot i \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

**$\left( 4. \right)$:**
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \exp\left( \ln\left( a + b \right) \cdot i \right) \quad\mid\quad \text{Euler's formula}\\
\left( a + b \right)^{i} &= \cos(\ln\left( a + b \right)) + \sin(\ln\left( a + b \right)) \cdot i\\
\end{align*}
$$

#### Simplification

If you want to solve the equation, you might want to note that you can simplify it even further using the [complex logarithmic forms of the inverse of trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) $\arcsin\left( z \right) = -i \cdot \ln\left( \sqrt{1 - z^{2}} + i \cdot z \right) = i \cdot \ln\left( \sqrt{1 - z^{2}} - i \cdot z \right)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
-i \cdot \ln\left( i \cdot x + \sqrt{1 - x^{2}} \right) &= \frac{1}{\left( i \cdot \ln\left( x \right) + \sqrt{1 - \ln\left( x \right)^{2}} \right)^{i}}\\
\arcsin\left( x \right) &= \exp\left( \arcsin\left( -\ln\left( x \right) \right) \cdot i \right)^{-i}\\
\end{align*}
$$

With this simplification, only $2\,$ $x$s remain.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment of jjag

Newton's binomial theorem is
$$
(1+x)^q = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{q}{k} x^k
$$
where $q,x$ are complex numbers, $|x|<1$, and the binomaial coefficient is
$$
\binom{q}{k} = \frac{q(q-1)(q-2)\cdots(q-k+1)}{k!} .
$$

Then we can do
$$
(a+b)^q = a^q\;\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)^q 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{q}{k} a^{q-k}b^k
$$
for $|a|>|b|$.

For $q=i=\sqrt{-1}$ we get
$$
{i\choose 0}=1,\\
{i\choose 1}=i,\\
{i\choose 2}=-{\frac{1}{2}}-{\frac {i}{2}},\\
{i\choose 3}={\frac{1}{2}}+{\frac {i}{6}},\\
{i\choose 4}=-{\frac{5}{12}},\\
{i\choose 5}={\frac{1}{3}}-{\frac {i}{12}}
$$